# Как во Vue работать с scss перменными

Tags: javascript, vue.js, scss

Можно ли как то взаимодействовать с переменными из scss во vue, например хочу сделать темную тему на сайт, и по нажатию на кнопки например переменная белый становится черной

Comment: тут классы надо использовать, а не переменные менять

Comment: ну как бы да, но мне просто интересно возможно ли такое

Comment: не ну нельзя, потому что scss компилируется в css, и на клиенте даже нет слова об scss

Comment: понятно, значит надо через стили это делать

Comment: заводите просто два класса грубо говоря `.dark_theme, .light_theme` и при клике просто заменяете их. просто тут надо грамотно построить сам scss, чтобы иерархия нормальная была